# Notepad++ Style comments with /**

Tags: styles, notepad++

I have a “.sql” file with 2 block comments:

```
/*
Comment
*/

/**
Comment
*/
```

[capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ax9Ew.png)

In the First block the colour style is the colour of the comments define.
But in the second block… No. The colour style is the base… no the colour of comments style.

Why?
It is possible to modify it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update your `stylers.xml` file. You should find it in your `C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++` directory. You find the following part:

```
    <LexerType name="sql" desc="SQL" ext="">
        ...
        <WordsStyle name="COMMENT" styleID="1" fgColor="008000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontName="" fontStyle="0" fontSize="" />
        <WordsStyle name="COMMENT LINE" styleID="2" fgColor="008000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontName="" fontStyle="0" fontSize="" />
    </LexerType>
```

and updated it to

```
    <LexerType name="sql" desc="SQL" ext="">
        ...
        <WordsStyle name="COMMENT" styleID="1" fgColor="008000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontName="" fontStyle="0" fontSize="" />
        <WordsStyle name="COMMENT LINE" styleID="2" fgColor="008000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontName="" fontStyle="0" fontSize="" />
        <WordsStyle name="COMMENT DOC" styleID="3" fgColor="008000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontName="" fontStyle="0" fontSize="" />
    </LexerType>
```

now it should color it as you want it.

Comment: Yes...it is correct. In my case... I use a personal theme then I change that line in xml file of folder theme... but it is ok... Also i include: 
            <WordsStyle name="COMMENT LINE DOC" styleID="15" fgColor="66747B" bgColor="0E1112" fontName="" fontStyle="0" fontSize="" />
            <WordsStyle name="COMMENT DOC KEYWORD" styleID="17" fgColor="66747B" bgColor="0E1112" fontName="" fontStyle="1" fontSize="" />
            <WordsStyle name="COMMENT DOC KEYWORD ERROR" styleID="18" fgColor="66747B" bgColor="0E1112" fontName="" fontStyle="1" fontSize="" />

Answer (score 1):

what about the following.

Use force at beginning of line
For comment line style use * as open
For comment style use the normal /* for open and */ for close
Now the trick
Use a delimiter and assign the same color as for comment
for open put in \\ \
and for close ((EOL)) ((EOL))

Looks like this does it. (note I used different colors for demonstration)

[image: Photp]